# How to wrap floated minted listing in my own environment?

Tags: listings, environments, minted, fancyvrb

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
\begin{code}{c}{Hello World in C}% I would prefer the caption to be optional
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{code}
```

The result should look like the picture below. (The caption is actually centered on the page but appears so because the image is cropped. Since this is a primitive example, I'm not concerned with prettifying the results.)

[image: code environment example]

I am trying to achieve that in my custom class by using [`minted`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) and the `listing` environment that it packages:

```
\newenvironment{code}[2]{%
    \begin{listing}\caption{#2}%
    \begin{minted}{#1}%
}{%
    \end{minted}%
    \end{listing}%
}
```

I get this error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> env.tex

? H
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

I suppose it has to do with the explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273206/252304), but I'd like to know if it can be done according to the interface shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the “inner” form of the commands. Rather than `listing`, I suggest to use the `newfloat` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted,newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=loc,
  listname=List of codes,
  name=Listing,
  placement=htp,
]{codefloat}

\newenvironment{code}[2][]
 {\codefloat
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\caption{#1}\fi
  \minted{#2}}
 {\endminted\endcodefloat}

\begin{document}

\begin{code}[Hello World in C]{c}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to have a look at the `verbments` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbments}

\begin{document}

\begin{pyglist}[language=c,caption=Hello world in C]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{pyglist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The verbments package seems to do what I want. Is there any way to alias the `pyglist` environment to something like `code`, as in my example?

Comment: @ladaghini Just add `\newenvironment{code}{\pyglist}{\endpyglist}` after `\usepackage{verbments}`

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to pass options into `\pyglist` in your example (e.g., change the language type)? I've never seend the `\pyglist` command before...

Comment: @opert `texdoc verbments`; you might want to look also at `minted` or `pythontex`